# To hyphenate or not to hyphenate, that is the question I ask of thee

Tags: hyphenation

Here is the sentence: The lady's headdress of a hat flew off.

Should it be headdress-of-a-hat?

thanks

Comment: What exactly is a *headdress-of-a-hat*? Are you trying to refer to "a headdress, consisting of a hat"?

Comment: Do not hyphenate this.

Comment: @Robusto I think it's a headress-like hat.  But, even so, I wouldn't hyphenate so much as find a better phrase to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only hyphenate the words for a phrase that modifies a noun.

In your example, "headress of a hat" would *not* be hyphenated, because "headress" is the subjective noun ("hat" is embedded in a prepositional phrase).

"headress-like hat" *would* be hyphenated, because hat is the subjective noun and "headress-like" is the adjectival phrase that modifies it.

(Note that this hyphenation rule doesn't apply to adverbs within an adjectival phrase, such as "unusually tall hat")